# When using the pen tool in AI/PS, how do I select different parts of the image to continue with my path?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, vector

Take this image for example:[image]

How would I then go and select more of the rabbit after I made that leg selection up into its body?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is flawed when referring to Adobe Illustrator. "How would I then go and select more of the rabbit after I made that leg selection up into its body?" In Illustrator you are not "selecting" the rabbit, you are drawing a path, making a line.

To continue a line you have already started click on the point that you want to continue drawing from. Here is a good tutorial: http://vector.tutsplus.com/tutorials/tools-tips/illustrators-pen-tool-the-comprehensive-guide/

This is what the icon will look like when you move the cursor over an end point: [image] or [image]

If the path has been closed, that is it has created a complete shape with no open end points, you will need to delete an anchor point to continue drawing.

Adobe Photoshop is a bit different, but the skills learned in Illustrator translate very well. Here is a good tutorial on using the pen tool to make selections in Photoshop: http://www.photoshopessentials.com/basics/selections/pen-tool-selections/

And here is a tutorial for drawing shapes in Photoshop using the pen tool. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/photoshop/cs/using/WSfd1234e1c4b69f30ea53e41001031ab64-73a0a.html

Answer (score 0):

To connect to an existing open path, click one of the end points with the Pen Tool.